# JSON Schema - Dynamic required properties

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a schema to validate an incoming JSON,

**JSON Schema**

```
{
    'title': 'storage schema',
    'description': 'storage schema',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties':{
        'title': {
            'title':'storage Name',
            'type': 'string',
            'minLength': 1,
            'maxLength': 255
        },
        'storageType': {
            'title': 'storage Type',
            'enum' : ['DVD', 'HDD', 'Network', 'Internet']
        },
        'minCapacity': {
            'title': 'Minimum Storage Capacity',
            'type': 'number'
        },
        'maxCapacity': {
            'title': 'Maximum Storage Capacity',
            'type': 'number'
        }
    },
    'additionalProperties':false,
    'required':['title', 'storageType']
}
```

I would like to have `minCapacity` and `maxCapacity` properties to be present in the json if `storageType` is `DVD` or `HDD` and not present in the json if the `storageType` is `Network`.

It can be done if i modify the schema to have storage as object and have min and max capacity as its properties, as in the schema below.

```
{
    'title': 'storage schema',
    'description': 'storage schema',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties':{
        'title': {
            'title':'storage Name',
            'type': 'string',
            'minLength': 1,
            'maxLength': 255
        },
        'storage': {
            'title': 'storage Details',
            'type': 'object',
            'oneOf' : [{'$ref': '#/storage/disk'},
                       {'$ref': '#/storage/network'}]
        },
    },
    'additionalProperties':false,
    'required':['title', 'storage'],
    'storage':{
        'disk':{
            'properties':{
                'type': {
                    'title': 'Storage Type',
                    'enum': ['HDD', 'DVD']
                },
                'minCapacity': {
                    'title': 'Minimum Storage Capacity',
                    'type': 'number'
                },
                'maxCapacity': {
                    'title': 'Maximum Storage Capacity',
                    'type': 'number'
                }
            },
            'additionalProperties': false,
            'required':['type', 'minCapacity', 'maxCapacity']
        },
        'network':{
            'properties':{
                'type': {
                    'title': 'Storage Type',
                    'enum': ['Network', 'Internet']
                }
            },
            'additionalProperties': false,
            'required':['type']
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like to achieve this without changing the structure of the schema.

Can it be done?

**Valid Json 1**

```
{
    'title': 'additional mandatory properties',
    'storageType': 'HDD',
    'minCapacity': 0.1,
    'maxCapacity': 1
}
```

**Valid Json 2**

```
{
    'title': 'no additional mandatory properties',
    'storageType': 'Network'
}
```

**Invalid Json 1**

```
{
    'title': 'additional mandatory properties',
    'storageType': 'Internet',
    'minCapacity': 0.1,
    'maxCapacity': 1
}
```

**Invalid Json 2**

```
{
    'title': 'no additional mandatory properties',
    'storageType': 'HDD'
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

when trying schema from [jason's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707486/2032074) answer, it was not validating when only, one of the non required parameters is present in the json. The invalid JSON are given below.

**Invalid Json 3**

```
{
    'title': 'additional mandatory properties',
    'storageType': 'Internet',
    'minCapacity': 0.1
}
```

**Invalid Json 4**

```
{
    'title': 'additional mandatory properties',
    'storageType': 'Internet',
    'maxCapacity': 1
}
```

I solved this problem with a small modification to the schema in the not required part, which is as below.

```
{
    "title": "storage schema",
    "description": "storage schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "title": "storage Name",
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 255
        },
        "storageType": {
            "title": "storage Type"
        },
        "minCapacity": {
            "title": "Minimum Storage Capacity",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "maxCapacity": {
            "title": "Maximum Storage Capacity",
            "type": "number"
        }
    },
    "required": ["title", "storageType"],
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "storageType": {
                    "enum": ["DVD", "HDD"]
                }
            },
            "required": ["minCapacity", "maxCapacity"]
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "storageType": {
                    "enum": ["Network", "Internet"]
                }
            },
            "allOf":[
                {"not": {"required": ["maxCapacity"]}},
                {"not": {"required": ["minCapacity"]}}
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
{
  "title": "storage schema",
  "description": "storage schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "title": "storage Name",
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 255
    },
    "storageType": {
      "title": "storage Type"
    },
    "minCapacity": {
      "title": "Minimum Storage Capacity",
      "type": "number"
    },
    "maxCapacity": {
      "title": "Maximum Storage Capacity",
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["title", "storageType"],
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "storageType": {
          "enum": ["DVD", "HDD"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["minCapacity", "maxCapacity"]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "storageType": {
          "enum": ["Network", "Internet"]
        }
      },
      "not": { "required": ["maxCapacity", "minCapacity"] }
    }
  ]
}
```

P.S.
Use of `"additionalProperties": false` is discouraged. Having to things like `#/anyOf/1/not` is an example of how this feature can be more trouble than it's worth.  Best practice is to simply ignore properties that don't belong.

Comment: Wow! I was so stuck up on trying to do something with `enum`, and `dependencies`, i totally missed out on solving this way.  I will try this out.

Comment: It works!.  But, it fails to validate when only one of the capacity properties is present.  I have updated the question with the two conditions, Invalid Json 3 and Invalid Json 4.

Comment: I fixed the problem using an allOf for the not required property. I have the updated the question with the modified schema.  If you have any feedback on that let me know.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  You need the `allOf`.  Sorry I missed that.